# Unit Tests Fails in Build Service But Not Locally

Tags: java, spring, junit, bamboo

Two tests fail in my build service that will not fail when ran locally.

What I've discovered is that when I execute `mvn clean test` locally the sort order of my test classes are alphabetical (package and class), but when ran in the build service they're seemingly random.

It is not my intention of needing a specific "order" so I'm definitely concerned that one test prior to another is hinting at an isolation issue. However, I don't think I can just tell maven to run classes in a certain order.

What can I do to try to reproduce?

*EDIT*

I cloned my build plan, but pointed at a forked repo (same code) and it ran successfully with no failed tests...

Comment: I don't think this is the best way but if you say that the order on build service is random, you can set the `runOrder` to random on your machine and hope to run into the same problem.

Comment: Tests shouldn't rely on order. Each test must run separately and clean resources in `@After` method. But anyway, could you provide code and exception why test fails?

Comment: @SergheyBishyr I totally agree, but they're failing because they do not run cleanly the order definitely seems like a faster way to reveal why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to execute `mvn -Dsurefire.runOrder=random clean test` for random order locally.

But even if your build fails locally, random order is not the best option to reproduce failures because of test order. If the tests are all green when run in alphabetical order, you might be able to make your build consistently fail with `mvn -Dsurefire.runOrder=reversealphabetical clean test`

There are also a couple of more options -- see [runOrder documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder)